# Scroll two view pagers at same time

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have two view pagers in a layout. One at the top and other at the bottom.

When I scroll one view pager, the other view pager should scroll too. But my problem , when top view pager is scrolled, only the top view pager is scrolled, bottom view pager doesn't scroll.

My code :

```
        topViewPager.setAdapter(topViewPagerAdapter);
        bottomViewPager.setAdapter(bottomPagerAdapet);
        tabLayout.setViewPager(topViewPager);
        tabLayout.setViewPager(bottomViewPager);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a listener:

```
mViewPager1.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Page scrolled to " + position);

        mViewPager2.setCurrentItem(position)
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}
});
```

I suppose the TabLayout should adjust by itself.

Comment: But it does not move smoothly, it moves all of a sudden, I want both view pagers to move simultaneously

Comment: I think you can extend `ViewPager` and override `onPageScrolled`, and call that from the `onPageScrolled` of the `OnPageChangeListener`. There is definitely something to do with those parameters